# How to configure package dependencies by an external file?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, package, delphi-2010, conditional-compilation

I would affect the installation of certain components in a package through a configuration file.
 
I try to write the .dpk of the package as follows:

```
package Package1;

{$I ..\CONFIG.INC}

{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO ON}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS ON}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION ON}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS ON}
{$REFERENCEINFO ON}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES OFF}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DESCRIPTION 'Personal component'}
{$IMPLICITBUILD OFF}

requires
  vcl,  
{$IFDEF THIRD_PARTY_SUPPORT}
  ThirdVcl,
{$ENDIF}
  rtl;

contains
  Component1 in 'Component1.pas',
{$IFDEF THIRD_PARTY_SUPPORT}
  Component2 in 'Component2.pas',
{$ENDIF}
  Component3 in 'Component3.pas';

end.
```

The file CONFIG.INC contains: {$Define THIRD_PARTY_SUPPORT}

Now, when I open the package the Component2 is not loaded, but if I write the Define directly into the Package, then the Component2 is loaded.
Is it possible to put the {$Define} in an external file? I use Delphi 2010.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Delphi 2010 uses DPROJ file. And different parts of Delphi put priority to DPK or DPROJ files. And you certainly cannot use $IfDef in Microsoft Build (DPROJ). I think the proper solution would be extracting conditional part into separate Package(s) and decide in runtime to load it or not after reading configuration

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought of that solution.

Comment: you're welcome. That one of "dependency injection" implementations. That one that VCL and whole Delphi IDE is based upon